# Как раздать интернет из Linux на Windows в VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-10, wifi, virtualbox, kali-linux

На **основной** машине стоит **Windows 10** и нет интернета. В качестве **Guest** выступает **Kali Linux**. В Kali Linux имеется некое подключение к интернету (**не обязательно по wlan0**, может быть и vpn).
Соответственно требуется "раздать" интернет (интерфейс **lo**) с Linux на Windows через VirtualBox.

[image: Схема того, что мне нужно]

Пробовал включать Host-only адаптер в VirtualBox, но так и не нашёл способ, как в Kali Linux расшарить на него интернет. Делал так: включал DHCP сервер у Host-only адаптера в VirtualBox, соответственно в Kali Linux он отображался как eth0 с известным IP, далее через менеджер подключений добавлял новое Ethernet-соединение и во вкладке IPv4 выбирал пункт "Shared to other connections" (так советуют в туториалах)

Как мне кажется, нужно каким-то образом натсроить iptables и NAT на Kali Linux, но в сетях я нуб.